# A functor between finitely complete categories which reflects limits, reflects finitely generated limits

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, functors

Let $\mathcal{B},\mathcal{C}$ be finitely complete categories, $F:\mathcal{B}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$ a functor that reflects finite limits and $\mathcal{D}$ a finitely generated category with $(f_i)_{1\leq i\leq n}$ generating its set of morphisms.

Let $G:\mathcal{D}\rightarrow\mathcal{B}$ be a functor. Suppose $(M,(q_D)_{D\in\mathcal{D}})$ be a cone over $G$ in $\mathcal{B}$ such that $(F(M),(F(q_D))_{D\in\mathcal{D}})$ is a limit of $F\circ G$ in $\mathcal{C}$. I have to show that $(M,(q_D)_{D\in\mathcal{D}})$ is a limit of $G$ in $\mathcal{B}$.

First of all, since $\mathcal{D}$ is finitely generated and $\mathcal{C}$ is finitely complete, there exists a limit $(L,(p'_D)_{D\in\mathcal{D}})$ of $G$ in $\mathcal{B}$. Thus it suffices to show that $M\cong L$. Note that $(F(L),(F(p'_D))_{D\in\mathcal{D}})$ is a cone over $F\circ G$. Hence there exists a unique morphism $m:F(L)\rightarrow F(M)$ in $\mathcal{C}$ such that
$$F(p_D)=F(q_D)\circ m$$
for $D\in\mathcal{D}$.

I'm not sure how to go on from this point. I still haven't used the fact that $F$ reflects finite limits: what I seem to have here are finitely generated limits not finite limits, so I'm not sure how to utilize this assumption.

Any suggestions?

**Edit:**

There exists a morphism $u:F(M)\rightarrow\prod_{D\in\mathcal{D}} F(G(D))$ in $\mathcal{C}$ such that $(F(M),u)$ is the equalizer of the unique morphisms $\alpha',\beta':\prod_{D\in\mathcal{D}} F(G(D))\rightarrow\prod_{i=1}^nF(G(t(f_i)))$.

Similarly, there exists a morphism $l:L\rightarrow\prod_{D\in\mathcal{D}} G(D)$ in $\mathcal{B}$ such that $(L,l)$ is the equalizer of the unique morphisms $\alpha,\beta:\prod_{D\in\mathcal{D}} G(D)\rightarrow\prod_{i=1}^nG(t(f_i))$. It follows that $\alpha'=F(\alpha)$ and $\beta'=F(\beta)$.

Furthermore, there exists a unique morphism $r:M\rightarrow\prod_{D\in\mathcal{D}}G(D)$ such that $q_D=p'_D\circ r$ for $D\in\mathcal{D}$. How to show that $F(r)=u$?

Comment: Yes, a category with finite limits does in fact have finitely generated limits. This is because the common codomain of the two parallel arrows in the usual construction of limits from products and equalizers can in fact be reduced to a finite product if $\mathcal{D}$ is finitely generated.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Thank you for your help. Would you please take a look at my edit? I need to get $u$ in the form $F(a)$, for some morphism $a\in\mathcal{B}$, in order to reflect the equalizer back into $\mathcal{B}$. I propose to use $r$.–is that a good candidate?

Comment: I feel like you might need that $F$ also preserves finite products to prove that $F(r)=u$, since what you have is that $F(\pi_D)F(r) = F(\pi_Dr)=F(q_D)=\pi_Du$ for all $D$, so you would need that $F(\pi_D)=\pi_D$, where the two $\pi_D$s are the appropriate projections to each category.